# Как преобразовать массив без ключей в двумерный массив с ключами?

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно из такого массива

```
$array = ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Коля'];
```

Сделать такой

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'Вася'],
    ['name' => 'Петя'],
    ['name' => 'Коля']
];
```

Желательно одной строчкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)

Одной строкой записать можно, но читается плохо.

Лучше разделить на несколько:

```php
$result = array_map(function($item) {
    return ['name' => $item]
}, $array);
```